# Which sound cards below are supported on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: sound, alsa, hardware, soundcard

I'm currently evaluating the following listed sound cards as possible replacement/addition for my onboard hda sound(card).

1. Creative Sound Blaster VX
2. Creative sound Blaster Audigy 7.1
3. Creative Sound Blaster Z
4. Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Xtreme Audio
5. Creative Sound Blaster Recon3D
6. Asus Xonar DGX
7. Asus Xonar DSX

Comment: For what its worth, I ended up getting a Creative Soundblaster X-Fi Xtreme Audio MSI Edition and it seems to work out of the box on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have a lot of headaches trying to get Creative sound cards to function in Linux. I would go with the ASUS cards. Also, you mean Ubuntu 14.04, right?

Comment: Right now, my desktop is running 13.10, but I'll get around to 14.04 eventually.  If it is supported on 14.04, that's swell too.

Comment: So, if I'm not mistaken, either of the Xonar cards should do?

Comment: Yes, ASUS sound cards work well. I once made the mistake of buying a Creative Recon3D, and there were times where it would not work for months despite any attempt to get it to function, and times where it worked months for no reason at all. Even when I did get it work (which I am using it right now), only the headphone ports work.

Comment: FYI - I have a Gateway computer that was given to me because Windoze XP is no longer supported at all. I figured it might not be too bad - it has a dual core Intel CPU - so installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it. It runs very nicely - not blazingly fast - however, I could not get the sound card to work for love nor money. I tried everything - every suggestion I could find on Google. Finally, as a last resort, I pulled the Sound Blaster Live 5.1 card out of an old computer. Then I read the above comment about getting Creative Labs cards to work on Linux. I figured I had nothing to lose so I put it in any